# Working how many sequences / permutations?

Tags: math, permutation

I have maths question.  I’m working on a piece of software that can accept 5 parameters.   While I have tested that the system can handle these parameters when entered individually and with a system reset I now need to verify that the system can handle the input of different sequences of inputs, for example

The user might input [1], [2], [3], [4], [5] or they might [2], [4], [5], [1], [3]

The first step I’m trying to achieve is to work out how many combinations there could be?  Any pointers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are `n` arguments, there are total `n!` permutations. Or at least this many, if omit that some arguments may be the same. In order to remove the duplicates, group the arguments by its value.

Let's say there are `n_0` times of value `x_0`, ..., `n_i` times of value `x_i`, ..., `n_m` times of value `x_m`. So there are total

```
(n_0 + n_1 + ... + n_m)!
------------------------
n_0! * n_1! * ... * n_m!
```

---

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets

Answer (score 0):

When you have `n` numbers, at least `n!` permutations exist.

In your case you want a permutation of a set, thus the total number is:

```
(n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5)!
------------------------------- 
n_1! * n_2! * n_3! * n_4! * n_5!
```

Read more about permutations in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).